# Bash Scripting: terminal and multiple other actions

Tags: bash, python-2.7, terminal, server, ubuntu-14.04

Let's say I'm accessing the terminal and performing an ssh command from a bash script. I'd also like to, after I've opened the ssh, perform a few more things like:

1. cd /srv/django
2. python manage.py shell
3. execfile 'home/usr/myscript.py'

My script file so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh server "python /srv/django/manage.py shell" execfile 'home/usr/myscript.py'
```

How could I go about performing this through the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` accepts a command for the remote system at the end of its command line, for example:

```
xterm -e ssh servercomp cd /srv/django \; python manage.py shell
```

Comment: hmm so it doesn't work with the entire command though..
 
xterm ssh servercomp 'cd /srv/django; python manage.py shell'

Comment: It's all in the quoting.  I've updated my answer to use backslash, which works through xterm.